# Bootstrap button alignment small screen width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

okay I'm styling some buttons for a mini survey site I am building and I am happy with how it looks on a desktop, but when i resize the browser window to a size that resembles a phone I cant get the buttons to just align under eachother. the desktop sized version has 2 rows, one with 3 buttons and one with 2 buttons.

full size desktop it looks ok : 
[image]

reduced width:
[image]

my button code :

```
<div class="panel-body" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified mg0 pd0"role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 mg0 pd0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" id="btnChoice1" value="<?php echo $aId[0];?>"><?php echo $aTitle[0];?></button>
        </div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 mg0 pd0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" id="btnChoice2" value="<?php echo $aId[1];?>"><?php echo $aTitle[1];?></button>
        </div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 mg0 pd0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" id="btnChoice3" value="<?php echo $aId[2];?>"><?php echo $aTitle[2];?></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><div class="row">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified mg0"role="group" aria-label="...">
          <div class="col-xs-6 mg0 pd0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" id="btnChoice4" value="<?php echo $aId[3];?>"><?php echo $aTitle[3];?></button>
          </div><div class="col-xs-6 mg0 pd0">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" id="btnChoice5" value="<?php echo $aId[4];?>"><?php echo $aTitle[4];?></button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the buttons to align themselves one per one under eachother instead of 2 buttons then one then 2 again and text getting outside the buttons in the second picture...

any help?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the class `class="col-xs-12"` instead of `class="col-xs-6'`to the button `divs`.

This means the buttons will occupy all 12 grid columns at the xs resolution, rather than 2 buttons at col-6

Comment: that works when the screen is small the buttons align under each other well, but the desktop size screen now has the 2 buttons under eachother instead of next to eachother so its now 3 buttons, 1 button ,1 button where 3 buttons, 2 buttons would be desired... thanks so far tho

Comment: You would be looking for something like: class="col-xs-12 col-md-6".

To explain, this means that at 'md' medium screen or greater the buttons will align in rows or 2. So 2 buttons side by side. If you want 3 buttons side by side, you should use col-md-4 instead

Comment: yeah I just noticed I added them for the lower two buttons and they now resize well.

Answer (score 0):

thanks i got it now the lower two buttons needed a declaration for md and now its fixed, i understand how it works now the grid xs md lg system ...

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified mg0 "role="group" aria-label="...">
          <div class="mg0 pd0 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" id="btnChoice4" value="<?php echo $aId[3];?>"><?php echo $aTitle[3];?></button>
          </div><div class="mg0 pd0 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" id="btnChoice5" value="<?php echo $aId[4];?>"><?php echo $aTitle[4];?></button>
          </div>
      </div>
```